# With Jquery ui's draggable, how do you change the revert on stop?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I was wondering how you changed the "revert" property of something being dragged in Jquery ui from the stop event.

```
    $('.things').draggable({ 
        revert: "true",
        stop: function(event, ui){
                        //if something then set revert to false
        }
    });
```

I've tried a few things but I can't seem to get it to work.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `stop` event occurs too late for changes to the `revert` option to affect the current drag operation. The draggable will still revert, even if it won't do so anymore in the next drags.

You might want to bind to the [drag](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-drag) event instead:

```
$('.things').draggable({ 
    revert: true,
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        if (/* something */) {
            $(this).draggable("option", "revert", false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That works but I don't want to attach some big processing to the drag, it slows it down considerably in IE and older FFs. Is there anything else in the lifecycle of the drag to attach it to, something pre-stop.

Comment: Alas, to my knowledge there is none. Can you give more details about the heavy processing you're performing to determine `something`? Maybe there's a better way to do what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this has been a while since this question was asked, but in JQuery UI 1.10 and above `draggable` now supports a function as a value for `revert`. If the value returns true then the position is reverted otherwise it does not.

```
$('.things').draggable({ 
    revert: function() {
        if(condition_is_met()) {
             return false; // Don't revert
        } else {
             return true;
        }
    }
});
```